# MemoryStream: System.ObjectDisposedException : Cannot access a disposed object

Tags: c#

The following function which is used to convert the string to `SqlXml` (**`System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlXml`**). However, it got the following runtime error? What's missing?

> System.ObjectDisposedException : Cannot access a disposed object.
>
> Object name: 'Invalid attempt to call Read when the stream is closed.'.

```
System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlXml GetXml(string s)
{
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
        settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;

        using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(memoryStream, settings))
        {
            xmlWriter.WriteString(s);
            return new SqlXml(memoryStream);
        }
    }
}
```

The error occurs in the last line.

```
var range = GetXml("<Range><Column Name=\"Id\" Low=\"3397\" High=\"8999\" /></Range>");
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@range", SqlDbType.Xml) { Value = range });
var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Answer (score 2):

Without a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and particularly details about the `SqlZml` class, it will be impossible to diagnose your problem perfectly. But…

You are disposing `memoryStream`. It seems that the `SqlXml` constructor does not read the stream immediately, but rather waits until you attempt to actually use the `SqlXml` object. Since you've already disposed the `memoryStream` object you passed to the `SqlXml` constructor, you get the exception when `SqlXml` then tries to read from that stream.

Without knowing what `SqlXml` is or how it's supposed to work, I can't say for sure what the right way to deal with this is. But most likely all you have to do is stop disposing the `memoryStream` object. I.e. don't include the `using` statement. A `MemoryStream` object doesn't really need to be disposed anyway (it doesn't hold any unmanaged resources), and assuming `SqlXml` is written correctly, it will take ownership of a `Stream` object passed to it. So all you need to do is remember to dispose the `SqlXml` object later, when you're done with it.

If the above does not address your concern, please improve the question by providing more detail, including a good MCVE and the specifics about the `SqlXml` class and how it works.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you post, the `SqlXml` object consumes the `memoryStream` instance as a dependency, and holds a reference to it within the scope of the new `SqlXml` object, but it doesn't do anything with it before the code reaches the `GetXml()` method's `return` statement.

The `using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())` block is fulfilled when `GetXml()` returns, so the runtime disposes the `memoryStream` instance. After that, the `SqlXml` object contains a reference to a disposed object, and an attempt to use that reference inside the `SqlXml` object results in the exception you experience.

A solution could be to make the `SqlXml` object implement `IDisposable`, so when `Dispose()` is called on that object, it disposes the `MemoryStream` itself. Then you can wrap the call to `GetXml()` in a `using` block:

```
using (SqlXml range = GetXml("...")) 
{
    ...
}
```